# React-hook-form never updates as dirty after user has made changes

Tags: react-hook-form

We're running a project in which react-hook-form has worked fine, however the dirtying doesn't function, and never has. It should activate once the useForm has gotten default values after which the user changes some of the fields.

What are some of the situations where the library might have the problem of not behaving correctly with dirtying?

Comment: You're probably better off finding the project on github and raising this as a bug or discussion.